# Slow wifi on specific network

Tags: wireless, internet

I've never had problems with any wifis but I changed workplace and my internet connection here is really slow. My coworkers use windows and mac and get like 8mbs of download speed (also slow) but I get only 1mb. 
Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Version

```
Linux version 4.4.0-121-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #145-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 13 13:47:23 UTC 2018
```

Comment: Hi MMrj, can you add more specific information to your question? For starters, please add which Ubuntu release and kernel version you have (execute `sudo cat /proc/version` in Terminal). What is your Internet provider at your new office? Also, if you've gone through any of the networking troubleshooting guides for Ubuntu, it would be really helpful to post the output of them into a pastebin and post a link in your question. `sudo lshw -C network` would be great for starters.

Comment: The [Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure) guide has a comprehensive list of diagnostic commands in Step 2; they are all crammed into a one-line command but you can execute them individually too.